# Bug with text of upvote/downvote reputation popup

Tags: bug, voting, tooltips, popup

I was looking at upvote and down vote requirements. I saw this.

When I upvote:
[image]

When I downvote:

[image]

It should specify that upvote has one requirement(15) and downvote has another(125). Right now the only difference between the prompts are the numbers it lists, it doesn't specify the difference.

Comment: The privilege thresholds for upvoting and downvoting are different: https://stackoverflow.com/privileges. This is not a bug.

Comment: @CodyGray Not OP, but it looks like the bug part is that the banner says the nearly the same thing, rather than e.g. "Upvotes ... less than 15 reputation" and "Downvotes ... less than 125 reputation"

Comment: @user10762409 CodyGray yes that is what I mean, I will fix the original post to clarify

Comment: So the "bug" is that you click on a vote, totally forget about that you've clicked and when are confused about the meaning of the reputation requirement? The banners don't need to mention the vote you've clicked on again, that context already exists.

Comment: No, it can cause confusion because people see two numbers and no separation. It isn't too hard to change what it says in the tooltip. It would add much more clarity